# ATM withdrawing money using only 50s and 20s bills C

Tags: c

How can I withdraw the right amount of money from ATM using only 20s and 50s bills? For example if I want to withdraw 130€ The machine should give me 1 bill of 50 and 4 bills of 20.

It's really difficult to make it work properly. Can somebody help me?

I can only do this much:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int balance = 500;
  int withdraw;
  int bill_20, bill_50;

  printf("How much you want to withdraw?");
  scanf("%d", &withdraw);

  if ((withdraw >= 20) && (withdraw <= balance) && (withdraw % 10 == 0)
      && (withdraw != 30)) {

    if (withdraw >= 50) {
      bill_50 = withdraw / 50;
      withdraw = withdraw % 50;
      printf("You get %d bills of 50s\n", bill_50);
    }
    if ((withdraw >= 20) && (withdraw < 50)) {
      bill_20 = withdraw / 20;
      withdraw = withdraw % 20;
      printf("You get %d bills of 20s\n", bill_20);
    }

  } else
    printf("Wrong sum");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does your current code fail?

Comment: `if (withdraw >= 50)` is an insufficient test.  When `withdraw== 50`, it makes sense, yet when `withdraw== 60`, better to supply 3 x 20s.

Comment: Should the bills be only 50 and 20?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, go step-by-step:

1. Take the biggest amount of 50s which fit.
2. If the rest cannot be taken in 20s, and we took at least one 50, put one 50 back.
3. Take as many 20s as fit for the rest.
4. If anything is left, despair.

```
int bill_50 = withdraw / 50 - (withdraw > 50 && withdraw % 50 % 20);
int bill_20 = (withdraw - bill_50 * 50) / 20;
if (withdraw != bill_50 * 50 + bill_20 * 20)
    printf("Cannot put it together.\n");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know you could do this " !!(withdraw % 50 % 20) "

Answer (score 1):

You can try subtracting the value each time from the `withdraw`. I modified your code like this. Hope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int balance = 500;
    int withdraw;
    int twenties = 0;
    int fifties = 0;

    printf("How much you want to withdraw?\n");

    scanf("%d", &withdraw);

    if (withdraw > balance) {

        printf("You don't have this kind of money.\n");

        return 0;
    }

    else if (withdraw <= 30 || withdraw % 10 != 0) {

        printf("You can only withdraw 20s and 50s.\n");

        return 0;
    }

    while (withdraw > 50) {

        twenties++;

        withdraw -= 20;
    }

    if (withdraw == 50) fifties++;

    else twenties += 2;

    printf("You got %d 20s and %d 50s\n", twenties, fifties);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. Now I just have to figure out how to use the least amount of bills possible.